# SQL - Get AVG from count from another table

Tags: sql, count, average

So I have 2 tables: Listing and Reviews.
I try to get the listing with the best reviews, which is based in a state. So I need to get the AVG from all reviews for the listing and then DESC the listings.

Table Structure:
Listing: id; title; state; ...

Reviews:
id; listing_id; rating (from 1-5)

I just could solve the DESC Listing of the most reviews but now I try to get the AVG of the rating of the reviews.

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM reviews rv 
         WHERE ls.id = rv.listing_id) Count 
  FROM listing ls 
 WHERE ls.state ='$get_state' 
 ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Sample Data:

```
Listing:

id title                State 
1  Hotel with nice view Arizona
2  Hotel to stay        Arizona

Review:

id listing_id rating
1  1          4(stars)
2  1          4(stars)
3  1          3(stars)
4  2          5(stars)
```

Listing id 1 got 3 reviews and a total star value of 11 / 3 reviews = 3.6 stars

Listing id 2 got 1 review and a total star value of 5 / 1 = 5 stars

now I should first get the Listing 2 and then the listing 1 
I want to display the whole thing on a PHP Page.

What can I do next?
Thanks for the help

Comment: provide sample data and expected result

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar done, thanks

Comment: please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar  
I have another problem... I added the function where you must confirm your email to get the review unlocked. Now I have in the review table a column named mail_approved. The problem is I just have to get the AVG rating of the reviews where mail_approved = 1. Where can I add this clause? Do I have to reformat the whole query? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use AVG() function to get the average rating

```
SELECT ls.id,
       title,
       state,
       ROUND(AVG(rating),2) avg_rating
  FROM listing ls
  JOIN review rv
    ON ls.id = rv.listing_id
 WHERE ls.state = '$get_state'
 GROUP BY ls.id,
          title,
          state
 ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
```

if you are using MSSQL, CAST column rating to get decimal precision (as float or decimal)

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST(rating AS FLOAT)),2) avg_rating
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked smooth!

Comment: I have another problem... I added the function where you must confirm your email to get the review unlocked. Now I have in the review table a column named mail_approved. The problem is I just have to get the AVG rating of the reviews where mail_approved = 1. Where can I add this clause? Do I have to reformat the whole query?

Thank you very much!